# Div relative size recalculating on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, window-resize, onresize

Greeting, everyone.

I'd like to ask you to help me with the following.
I've made this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdthnpkg/62/) to illustrate my problem.

I'm trying to make div pattern with diagonals. May be I'm thinking in the wrong direction but this is the only solution I could imagine.
Anyway, there two main problems with this.

1. In my solution I have 100s cloned units: the `.square` is the main
   unit, it has four cloned `.background` subunits and each of the
   latter contains appended `.diagonal` that is the rotated div. All
   the sizes depend on the size of the `.square`. And in its turn, the
   size of `.square` depends on `$(window).width/20`. I'm trying to
   create autoresizing pattern to have 20 units in the row on any
   window width. But in any solution it either crashes not depending on the amount of the `.square`'s (even `e < 1` leads to crash) or resizes nothing but the `.square:nth-of-type(1)`.
2. As I've mentioned, there are 100s cloning processes. And the DOM
   increases with lightning speed. So is there any more elegant way to
   reach the same result I'm willing? Or Is there a way to clone
   without registering in the DOM?

Thanks in advance. Everything would help.

Comment: Is this for a background?? If so, you can do it easily with css using a part of the pattern, putting it with `background-image` and reapiting it with `background-repeat`

Comment: Yes, that's for background but it needed to be made with code not with image, e.g. to make [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cdthnpkg/64/) possible

Comment: Ok, I see the effect... Just tell you that it can be done with a `.gif` image as a background too! Let's see if someone can recommend you something about jQuery...